# How to hide/show a fixed element when scrolling some sections into view vertically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a fixed element `#logoimode3` to hide/show when some sections scroll into view vertically.

For example:
Show `#logoimode3` when `#section1` and `#section3` scroll into view
Hide `#logoimode3` when #section2 scrolls into view

So the fixed element should disappear when the blue section scrolls into view. And then show again when the green section scrolls into view.
I want my logo to disappear while scrolling through `#section2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML code:

```html
    <img id="logoimode3" class="logo3" style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;" src="https://imode.info/imode/slike/ikone/IMODE_znak-01.svg" alt="logo" height="" width="30px">
    <section id="section1" style="background: red; height:100vh;"></section>
    <section id="section2" style="background: blue; height:100vh;"></section>
    <section id="section3" style="background: green; height:100vh;"></section>
    <footer></footer>
```

Here is my JavaScript code:

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#logoimode4').css({
        'display': 'none'
    });

    $(function() {
        var $window = $(window);
        var logo = $('#logoimode4');
        var div1 = $('#section1stran');
        var div2 = $('#section2stran');
        var div3 = $('#section3stran');
        var div4 = $('#section4stran');
        var div5b = $('#section5bstran');

        var div1_height = div1.height();
        var div2_height = div2.height();
        var div3_height = div3.height();
        var div4_height = div4.height();
        var div5b_height = div5b.height();

        $window.on('scroll', function() {
            var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            var viewport_height = $window.height();
            var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;

            //   if (scrollTop >= 0 && (scrollTop_bottom <=  div1_height * 1.9 )) {
            //     logo.css({'display' : 'none'});
            //    }

            if (scrollTop >= div1_height * 0 + div1_height * 1 + div2_height + div3_height + div4_height + div5b_height && (scrollTop_bottom <= div1_height * 5 + div1_height + div2_height + div3_height + div4_height + div5b_height)) {
                logo.css({
                    'display': 'block'
                });
            } else {
                logo.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                });
            }

            // Work with Class
            /* if (scrollTop > div1_height && (scrollTop_bottom <= div1_height * 3)) {
                logo.addClass('hidden');
            } else {
                logo.removeClass('hidden');
            } */
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is what you need with the full code:

```js
$(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var logo = $('#logoimode3');
  var div1 = $('#section1');
  var div1_height = div1.height();

  $window.scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewport_height = $window.height();
    var scrollTop_bottom = scrollTop + viewport_height;

    if (scrollTop > div1_height && (scrollTop_bottom <= div1_height * 3)) {
      logo.css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
    } else {
      logo.css({
        'display': 'block'
      });
    }

    // Work with Class
    /* if (scrollTop > div1_height && (scrollTop_bottom <= div1_height * 3)) {
        logo.addClass('hidden');
    }
    else {
        logo.removeClass('hidden');
    } */
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="logoimode3" class="logo3" style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;" src="https://imode.info/imode/slike/ikone/IMODE_znak-01.svg" alt="logo" height="" width="30px">

<section id="section1" style="background: red; height:100vh;"></section>
<section id="section2" style="background: blue; height:100vh;"></section>
<section id="section3" style="background: green; height:100vh;"></section>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why this code does not work in Safari browser? (but it work ok in Crome, Firefox, ...) - numbers does not change when i check with console log (srollTop, heights, ... ). Thank you

Comment: Chenged to:    $(window).scroll(function() { 
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); and now it works

Answer (score 1):

get height of section and when the top of section hits 0 it hides and when the bottom of section hits 0 it shows again

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <style></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      var sec2 = document.getElementById("section2");
      var pos = sec2.getBoundingClientRect();
      var height1 = pos.height * -1;
      if (pos.top < 1 && pos.top > height1) {
        jQuery('#logoimode3').hide();
      }
      else if(pos.top < height1 || pos.top > 1) {
        jQuery('#logoimode3').show();
      }
    });
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
      var sec2 = document.getElementById("section2");
      var pos = sec2.getBoundingClientRect();
      var height1 = pos.height * -1;
      if (pos.top < 1 && pos.top > height1) {
        jQuery('#logoimode3').hide();
      }
      else if(pos.top < height1 || pos.top > 1) {
        jQuery('#logoimode3').show();
      }
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <img id="logoimode3" class="logo3" style="position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;" src="https://imode.info/imode/slike/ikone/IMODE_znak-01.svg" alt="logo" height="" width="30px">

  <section id="section1" style="background: red; height:100vh;"></section>
  <section id="section2" style="background: blue; height:100vh;"></section>
  <section id="section3" style="background: green; height:100vh;"></section>
  <section id="section4" style="background: pink; height:100vh;"></section>

</body>

<footer></footer>

</html>
```